# ECMA 262/Perl 5 regexp support in java

Tags: java, regex, rhino, ecma262

Are there any libraries that supports this regexp-specification in java?

Know the Mozilla Rhino uses this specification, but how can this be implemented in java?

UPDATE:
Found a library called jakarta-oro that supports perl5-regular expression which uses ecma-262.

http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If Rhino supports it, why not use the Rhino scripting support in Java to use Rhino? Look up [JSR-223](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=223), and you can use javascript in a Java application if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks. You can use the native javascript support in java to, but a framework that supports the regexp standard would be preferable.